# How to open modified in git file for edit in sublime

Tags: powershell, command-line, cmd, sublimetext2, sublimetext

The use case is the following

- you modified some files and `git status` shows them to you
- you want to edit one of those files in `Sublime`
- you feel hacky and want to do this from command line

using `Vim` you can do the following:

`vim 'git status --porcelain | grep "myfile.txt" | cut -c 4-'`

I use Sublime and Windows and don't know how to accomplish the same. Sublime seems to have `--command` command, but I can't get it to work. So the question is how to do that? (I am okay with `powershell`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In powershell you can do it like that:

```
sublime $(git status --porcelain | grep "myfile.txt" | cut -c 4-)
```

Answer (score -1):

Open all modified/deleted/new files:

```
vim `git status --porcelain | awk '{print $2}'`
```

Comment: The question says the platform is windows and the editor should be Sublime.

Comment: Hmm, right, actually I found this question when googling "how to open alll modified files with git" and figured out an answer, maybe I should just post my own question+answer?

Comment: That would be very great, very stack overflow ;)